# Unable to install autodock vina (potentially due to boost)

Tags: python, c++, boost, conda

As part of a script I am writing, I need to install the package autodock vina for the purpose of ligand and protein binding. Every time I attempt to "pip install vina", I recieve an error message " ValueError: Boost library location was not found!". Upon attempting to install boost manually, I have been unable to run the bootstrap file, as it does not make the b2 folder that online tutorials say it will make.

To resolve this issue, I installed conda, and made an active environment with every single prerequisite, including boost, installed. I have checked for the version of all of these prerequisites and confirmed their existence, as well as double and triple-checking that I am in the write active environment. Upon installation, I either get the same issue (using conda install vina) or when using "conda install -c bioconda autodock-vina", I get a message saying that the package does not exist (despite adding cforge and bioconda as active package handlers, and the existence of said package is clearly documented online). Does anyone have any suggestions? I've been attempting to install this piece of software for 3 days and I've completely exhausted the documentation, as well as all other similar question answers, with nothing working.

Full error message:

```
Collecting vina
  Using cached vina-1.2.3.tar.gz (95 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [56 lines of output]
      Version found 1.2.3 (from __init__.py)
      running egg_info
      creating vina.egg-info
      writing vina.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to vina.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to vina.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to vina.egg-info\top_level.txt
      writing manifest file 'vina.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      Boost library is not installed in this conda environment.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 177, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 159, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 174, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 346, in <module>
          setup(
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 308, in run
          self.find_sources()
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 315, in find_sources
          mm.run()
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 550, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 587, in add_defaults
          sdist.add_defaults(self)
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 228, in add_defaults
          self._add_defaults_ext()
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 311, in _add_defaults_ext
          build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
          cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r7vbpka4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
          self.finalize_options()
        File "setup.py", line 247, in finalize_options
          raise ValueError(error_msg)
      ValueError: Boost library location was not found!
      Directories searched: conda env, /usr/local/include and /usr/include.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Answer (score 1):

I also get this error. I asked ResearchGate how to solve this problem and [Cheng Shen adviced](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_install_Autodock_Vina_via_pip_or_conda_in_Windows) to use WSL/WSL2 to simulate a Linux environment and then run `conda install -c bioconda vina` (or another command like this)

What I did.

1. [Install WSL and Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) on Windows 2. Run `code .` in WSL terminal (for installing VS Code [recommended])
2. Install Anaconda/Miniconda following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/kauffmanes/5e74916617f9993bc3479f401dfec7da)
3. Type `conda install -c bioconda vina` in Ubuntu terminal (bioconda channel will download all required packages - boost, swig, etc.)
4. Vina should be successfully installed ( `vina --version` in WSL Terminal to check)

I found it much easier to install packages for docking via WSL and use VS Code to run scripts there. It's VERY easier than trying to solve this problem by configuring boost for Windows. If you have any questions you can ask me in [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Artem-Petrov-7).

Comment: I found that if you use `conda install -c bioconda autodock-vina` package manager install vina1.1.2. Instead it i recommend use `conda install -c conda-forge vina` to install vina1.2.3, especially if you want do multiple ligand docking